# Frequency data frame for grouped bar plot

Tags: r

I am trying to create a grouped bar plot using ggplot2 (but could be other package). I realize there are several other posts similar to this, but I was unable to find anything that answered my specific questions, so, I apologize if it seems redundant. Searching other questions and answers I produced the following code:

```
### To remove unwanted rows from the larger data set###

NestPatch=NestPatch[,c(3,34)]

### Reshape data frame ####

dfm <- melt(NestPatch[,c("VOR2Binned", "Factor")],id.vars = 1)
```

I would like to have VOR2Binned on the X axis, Frequency on the Y, and VOR2Binned grouped by the Factor variable (0 or 1), which I would like to rename as Used and Random.

Here is my sample data:

```
Factor VOR2Binned   

0   3
1   3
0   3
1   3
0   2
1   2
1   3
0   2
1   3
0   2
0   3
1   3
0   3
1   3
0   3
1   3
1   2
0   3
0   0
```

I end up with the following ordered dataframe using the above code.

```
VOR2Binned   variable   value

0   Factor  0
0   Factor  0
0   Factor  0
0   Factor  0
0   Factor  0
2   Factor  1
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  1
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
2   Factor  0
3   Factor  0
3   Factor  1
3   Factor  1
```

If I continue with

```
    #### Plot ####
   ggplot(dfm,aes(x = VOR2Binned,y = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = value),stat = "identity",position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

I get "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Factor' not found".

I think I am missing the step for developing the frequencies of each of the VOR2Binned classes.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? At the very least, you should provide `str()` of the data. A MWE will help you understand your dataset and where you may be falling short.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of understanding, but would like to provide the adequate information. What is an MWE? What is the best way to provide a str() of the data on this platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using data.table...

```
# generate your sample data
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(structure(list(
Factor = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), VOR2Binned = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L)), .Names = c("Factor","VOR2Binned"), 
row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

# count occurrences for each VOR2Binned
dt[, Frequency := .N, by=.(VOR2Binned, Factor)]

# let's make sure column Factor is really a factor
dt$Factor <- as.factor(dt$Factor)
# change name to Used and Available
levels(dt$Factor) <- c("Used", "Available")

# let's ggplot it!
ggplot(dt) + geom_col(aes(VOR2Binned, Frequency, fill=Factor),
                       position="dodge")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Is there any reason not to use data.frame? I only ask because of the way User 'baci' presented his answer.

Comment: I guess not, it's just that counting frequency uses .N which is specific to data.table. If you count frequency using some other method the rest of the code should work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, of course after hours of working at this, I found an alternative way to do it moments after posting the question .

```
dfm <- melt(NestPatch[,c("VOR2Binned", "Factor")],id.vars = 3)
dfm <-with(NestPatch, table(VOR2Binned, Factor)) 
tbl <- with(NestPatch, table(Factor, VOR2Binned)); barplot(tbl, beside = TRUE, legend = TRUE)
```

[Used Available Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMGmf.png)

I was missing the step of building a data table.

This will suffice for now to visualize the data, but I still would like to figure out how to do it with ggplot, if anyone can be of assistance. Also, if anyone knows how to modify the legend from the current factor codes of 1 and 0 to used and available that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As another follow up, is there a simple way of modifying the Y axis as percentage or having percentage of observations above each bar?